# "Error refreshing state: AccessDenied: Access Denied status code: 403" when using Okta SSO to perform terraform init/plan/apply. Can be fixed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am building some resources in 1 AWS account with terraform, but I am storing terraform state remotely on another AWS account.

Example of terraform code:

```
provider "aws" {
  region  = "us-east-1"
  profile = "AWS account 1"
}
terraform {

  backend "s3" {
    bucket         = "bucket name"
    region         = "us-east-1"
    key            = "terraform.tfstate"
    dynamodb_table = "locks"
    profile = "AWS account 2"
  }

}
```

with .aws/credentials

```
[AWS account 1]
aws_access_key_id=33333333333333
aws_secret_access_key=44444444444444444444

[AWS account 2]
aws_access_key_id=111111111111
aws_secret_access_key=22222222222222222222
```

When I am NOT using SSO to login to AWS and just using access and secret keys in .aws/credentials everything worked fine.

However, when I change to login into AWS with SSO and assume roles, things got ugly with .aws/config (with sso .aws/config should be used)

```
—
[okta]
aws_saml_url = [some aws_saml_url]

[profile AWS account 1-umbrella]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::[some accountID]:role/[some role_name]
region = us-west-1

[profile AWS account 1]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::[some accountID]:role/[some role_name]
source_profile = AWS account 1-umbrella
region = us-west-1

[profile AWS account 2-umbrella]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::[some accountID]:role/[some role_name]
region = us-west-1

[profile AWS account 2]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::[some accountID]:role/[some role_name]
source_profile = AWS account 1-umbrella
region = us-west-1
```

I am getting error "Error refreshing state: AccessDenied: Access Denied status code: 403".
or I am getting "Error: error configuring S3 Backend: Error creating AWS session: SharedConfigAssumeRoleError: failed to load assume role for arn:aws:iam::[some account id]:role/[some role name], source profile AWS account 1-umbrella has no shared credentials"

Does anyone has any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: I think SSO is not supported by TF.

Comment: see this link https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/single-sign-on-between-okta-universal-directory-and-aws/ , and the last section, you need to use `aws sso configure` and see this link also https://www.okta.com/blog/2020/05/how-okta-aws-sso-simplifies-admin-and-adds-cli-support/#:~:text=The%20AWS%20CLI%20is%20a,%2DFactor%20Authentication%20(MFA).